# How to turn off inertia when player stops moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I release the character control button, character itself continues to move for about half a second. I want the character to stop right after I release the control button. I’ve tried diffirent methods: `AddForce` and `velocity`, but it’s all in vain.

Also, I tried to adjust the **mass** and **drag momentum** in Inspector of the character, but it didn’t help.

```
public class CapsuleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    Vector3 playerMovement;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 50;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ProccessCapsuleMovement();
    }

    void ProccessCapsuleMovement () 
    {
        playerMovement = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        playerMovement.Normalize();

        rb.velocity = playerMovement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't normalize! If the Input magnitude is actually smaller than `1` you still normalize it always to a magnitude `1`!

  Rather use [`Vector3.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html) which only limits the magnitude in the upper bound but allows it to be smaller
- The other point might be that [`GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) is actually "smoothed" and not applied immediately! After releasing the button it is actually decreased over time. So since you normalized the vector it keeps having a magnitude of `1` for a while after releasing the buttons.

  You might rather want to use [`GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) for this.
- Then when assigning a velocity you do **not** want to multiply by `Time.deltaTime`! This only is needed where you want to convert a value from a fixed `value per frame` into a frame-rate-independent `value per second`. A velocity already **is** a `vector per second` so remove the `* Time.deltaTime`.

so something like e.g.

```
playerMovement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")), 1f);

rb.velocity = playerMovement * speed;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But now the speed of character is very slow

https://imgur.com/gallery/Ee6SKpm

Comment: @Vitaly yeah just edited the answer and added the third point: You don't want `Time.deltaTime` when assigning a velocity since this velocity already **is** framerate-independent ;)